# a cron job to delete a specific file once it reaches more then 1gb size?

Tags: linux, cron

My server broke down with exenstive damages when a log file reached 27 gigs in a few hours. Log files are compressed daily, and are usually very small, maybe up to 10mb in 24 hours. Today there was an issue, and it caused a stack trace to be printed 20 times a second, I was sleeping, the log turned into 27gb, and when hard drive became full, serious damages and data loss occured.
The log file will always be called "latest.log"
I need a cron job that will delete this file if it becomes larger then 1GB to prevent this train wreck in the future.
Thanks for helping me.

Comment: can you be more specific? Some frameworks allow you to define rotation and/or a max log size.

Comment: you can limit a process's max file size with `ulimit -f`.

Comment: but then the process does not hangs, meuh?

Comment: Anything that prints such messages without limiting rate (or just printing the first few before giving up the chatter, or just quitting if a serious problem repeats too often) is suspicious of not-up-to-snuff programming...

Answer (score 1):

I would not do it with a cron, albeit if you insist in that, a simple line of find would do that. Be aware that you would need to restart the service, because files in Unix only die when they are not being used anymore.

Back in crontab:

```
*/10 * * * * find /dir -name latest.log -size +1GB -exec rm -f {} \; -exec command_to_restart_your_service \;
```

As you talk about stacks, I assume you are talking about tomcat. Have a look at the following post. Nevertheless, if that server is so important, I would forward all the logs to a remote log server. Why are you having damages, are you running an SQL server there too? I would run it in a separate server.

Here is the link to the article about limiting logs in size.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342336/how-to-set-maximim-number-of-rolls-and-maximum-log-size-for-tomcat

Comment: No, it's latest.log from java minecraft. You said you didn't want me to use a cron job, what do you suggest instead? I'm very inexperienced and I welcome any help or advice. 
Do I just put "find /home/minecraft/multicraft/servers/server1/ -name latest.log -size +1GB -exec rm -f {} \" in  /etc/rc.local?

Comment: I edit it out for running every 10 minutes from cron. Mind you the cron must be the user which is running java, or root. I did not put such a long dir name just for clarity.

Comment: deleting the file does not help if a process still has it open.  even truncating it will not help (the nameless file keeps on growing as writes happen).  you need to restart whatever is logging there to get it to re-open that file (after you delete it).  in unix/linux, removing a file only remove the name. the file only goes away once there are zero names *and* zero opens.

Comment: you should be careful with running `-exec rm -f` it will automatically delete any files the find algorithm matches. you should at least test the command first by replacing `-exec rm-f` with `-exec ls -l`

Comment: exactly. I mentioned it in the comments earlier and forgot about it here. Will correct.

Comment: And testing first the command on the command line as @user4668401 suggests.

Comment: i did something similar to this, once, but instead of removing the file, i renamed it and queued a task to compress the named new name (repeating logs usually compress very well ... though 27 GB could take quite a while).

Comment: I would look into using *logrotate* - managing log files when they hit a pretermined size or date is exactly what  its designed for. Or as @RuiFRibeiro suggests - getting the logs off the server is a good idea - you could do that with *rsyslog*

Comment: The problem with logrorate is that it runs once a day, not in a extreme situation of a stack trace of a few hours as the poster describes. You could also argue we could lunch it manually, I would not advise it for the sake of keeping a consistent history of the server logs in syslog/messages and others.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: you can run logrotate with a different config (and state) file, that way it won't collide with other system logs. (And I think file-age checks can be disabled, too.)

Comment: Now that is a very interesting idea to tackle with some ran away log files I have here done by the dev team @ulrich

Comment: @Skaperen this is strictly for an emergency where it's 27 gigs of the same error. There wouldn't be a purpose for storing data like this. 
Also all this advice isn't really helpful as I kind of need like spoon fed tutorial. Anyway I honestly wouldn't mind deleting that log anyway.
Is there any possible way to just make the /log/ folder only have 1gb storage? idk what to do, but i would like there to be a task that would just delete a designated file whenever its over 1gb.

Comment: You can create partitions for logs, or limit the logs with security, however depending on the importance of having the service running it could not be the best of the ideas. If you do not mind of having it down for a few hours, sure it is the easiest of the solutions.